# How can I make sure that a line and spline join smoothly (C2 continuity)?

Tags: geometry, continuity, spline

I have a sequence of geometric items that I need to join smoothly to create a smooth path.  When points are far enough apart, they will be joined by a straight line.  When they are too close together, the number of close points are joined by an interpolating cubic B-spline.  How can I design the Bspline so that the joining point between a straight line and Bspline is C2 continous?  I will be using the algorithm `A9.2 SolveTridiagonal` from *The NURBS Book* to generate the cubic interpolating spline.  This algorithm depends on setting the first derivatives at the endpoints.  I could easily set the first derivatives at the endpoints to have equal directions as the straight lines, but is this enough to guarantee what I want?  Or do I need a specific magnitude for these derivatives?

Comment: To ensure C² continuity, the second derivatives of the cubic B-spline at the join point also need to be zero. How you do ensure that, depends on how the spline is defined, but in general, it is a separate constraint. (That is, usually the length of the endpoint tangent (first derivatives at endpoint) is a free variable, constrained to be positive.) Because the book, and the algorithm you refer to, are not publicly available, only those who have the book *and* are willing to look up the details before answering, can help you.  I don't have the book myself.